# How to write a custom checkstyle check to verify content of XML file?

Tags: java, maven, liquibase, checkstyle

I'm wondering is it posssible to write a custom checkstyle check that checks a file other then java source? For instance from src/main/resources? fiels like a liquibase changeset (it is a XML file)?

**I do not have liquibase PRO licence to write my own liquidbase check and run it.*

Comment: what should that checkstyle check actually?

Comment: I have put an example here - liquibase that uses changeset file which is in XML format. File contains fields that I want to check togather with other checks from checkstyle which operate on JAVA files. What is not clear for you here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what `liquibase` is.

Possible, yes, but you will need to build out the new parser and checks that will go against the new file type. Its not a simple, easy process. Without the parser, you will have to rely on regexp or string based matching which can be very flawed.

I myself tried to start things like this at https://github.com/rnveach/checkstyle-extras/ for my work but things changed for me and I don't really have the energy to build this out myself.